# Encrypting and decrypting with public and private RSA keys in JAVA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to do a simple encrypt/decrypt with asymmetric keys in JAVA using RSA keys and i have some troubles. This is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class AsymmetricCipherTestFiles 
{
    public static void main(String[] unused) throws Exception 
    {
        // 1. Generating keys
        System.out.println("Generating keys ...");
        PublicKey publicKey;
        PrivateKey privateKey;
        // generateKeys(512);

        // 2. read them from file
        System.out.println("Read from file");
        publicKey = readPublicKeyFromFile("public.key");
        privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFileTest("private.key");

        System.exit(0);

        // 3. encrypt data
        System.out.println("Encrypt data");
        byte[] dataBytes = "some string to encrypt".getBytes();
        byte[] encBytes = encrypt(dataBytes, publicKey, "RSA");
        printByteArray(encBytes);

        // 4. decrypt data
        byte[] decBytes = decrypt(encBytes, privateKey, "RSA");
        printByteArray(decBytes);
        // String decryptedThing = convert(decBytes);

    }

    public static void generateKeys(int keySize) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException 
    {
        // Create key
        // System.out.println("Generating keys");
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(keySize);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        /*
        Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        */

        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(),RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

        saveKeyToFile("bin/public.key", pub.getModulus(), pub.getPublicExponent());
        saveKeyToFile("bin/private.key", priv.getModulus(),priv.getPrivateExponent());

        // System.out.println("Keys generated");
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] inpBytes, PublicKey key,String xform) throws Exception 
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] inpBytes, PrivateKey key,String xform) throws Exception 
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
    }

    public static String convert(byte[] data) 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++ i) 
        {
            if (data[i] < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            sb.append((char) data[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static PublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream) AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.class.getResourceAsStream(keyFileName);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream( in ));
        try 
        {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
            return pubKey;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
        } finally {
            oin.close();
        }
    }

    public static PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream) AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.class.getResourceAsStream(keyFileName);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream( in ));
        try 
        {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[512];
            byteArray = m.toByteArray();

            KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(byteArray);
            // RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
            return privateKey;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
        } finally {
            oin.close();
        }
    }

    public static PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFileTest(String filename) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException
    {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int)raf.length()];
        raf.readFully(buf);
        raf.close();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec kspec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(buf);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(kspec);

        return privKey;
    }

    public static void saveKeyToFile(String fileName,BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException 
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        try 
        {
            oout.writeObject(mod);
            oout.writeObject(exp);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            oout.close();
        }
    }

    public static void printByteArray(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        int increment = 0;
        for(byte b : byteArray)
        {
            System.out.println("B["+increment+"] = "+b);
            increment++;
        }
    }
}
```

When i run it it gives me this error :

```
Generating keys ...
Read from file
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.readPrivateKeyFromFileTest(AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.java:160)
    at AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.main(AsymmetricCipherTestFiles.java:40)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

The thing is that at **generating/reading/encrypting** with **public key** everything works smoothly, the error occurs when reading **private key** and trying to get it into an `PrivateKey` object.

What i am doing wrong and how i may solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: ObjectOutputStream is a bad choice for saving public/private key. Use `getEncoded()` on the keys for getting data in x.509/PKCS#8 format.

Comment: thanks for the response, first of all, what is `x.509/PKCS#8` and how i may use `getEncoded()` function ??

Comment: If you don't know a term please first ask Google/Wikipedia then ask here again... `getEncoded`is a method that is available on every Key instance, therefore also on `PublicKey`and `PrivateKey`. Note: I made a mistake a public key is of course not encoded to x.509 (not sure what standard is used for that pkcs#1?).

Answer (score 2):

You're saving the key with two `writeObject()` calls but retreiving it with a single `readFully()` call. You need to either:

- save the key with `write(byte[])`, supplying the result of `getEncoded()`, *and* read it with `readFully(),` *or*
- save it with `writeObject()` and read it with `readObject().`

Not a mixture of the two.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, i don't quite get it, i also get error with the function `public static PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String keyFileName)` it is http://pastebin.com/tDzERLQF ... can you help me modify the function `readPrivateKeyFromFile` ? thanks in advice

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with your new code without seeing the new code. If you have an amendment to this question you should edit it. And no links please, or pictures of text. Just the code and the error message or exception stack trace.